# How to configure docker-compose to restart container which exitted with code 0 on set interval

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a container that needs to run every 6 hours. The container exits with code 0 once the process is completed. How to configure the docker-compose.yml to restart the container at 6hour interval.

Thank!

Comment: Is there a reason the container exits instead of running a while loop in the code that sleeps for 6 hours?

Comment: Its a ETL setup and once the sync is complete the process ends. Will check if the docker file can be configured to have a loop and sleep for 6hrs or if i can have it run using a command in docker-compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on linux? If yes then the easiest would be a `cron job` schedule(`0 */6 * * *`) with `docker restart <container_name>`

Comment: Your answer has value, but it doesn't address the OPs question directly.  A good answer to this question, IMO, assuming that docker-compose can't do this, should begin with "You can't do that with docker-compose because..." where a reason is given as to why.  Then alternatives, like what you have already provided, can follow after that. - there's also the question of modifying the behavior of the mechanism based on the return code of the job, as that seems to be part of the OPs question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
Yes, I'm running it on Linux will have to go with this approach if can't have it in docker-compose. My requirement needs the deployment happen over one command.